# If I start a fresh Android project, is it possible to roll it out as an update to an existing one?

Tags: android, deployment, google-play, updates

The original project has become cluttered and messy after a series of developers. Ideally we'd like to start from scratch code-wise, but would prefer not to have to put up a new app in the Play Store. Is it possible to have Google Play treat a fresh project as an update to an existing app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can publish it as an update, but three conditions have to be met:

1. The package name must be the same.  If your previous app package was `com.mycompany.myapp`, then the new app must have the same package (in AndroidManifest)
2. The version code in AndroidManifest must be higher than the last published one.
3. The app must be signed using the same key as the previous app.

Answer (score 0):

If it has the same package name and you have the passwords for your keystore and you have your keystore yes it can be rolled out as an update

Answer (score 0):

If it has the same package name and the passwords for your keystore yes it can be rolled out as an update